# Hard to get into 1st and 2nd gear, when clutch is pressed against the left side

Tags: transmission, nissan, clutch, manual-transmission, gear-stick

I have a manual Nissan Qashqai dci, where when I hold the clutch stick left, in order to switch to 1st or 2nd gear, I find it very difficult or almost impossible. I have to hold the stick lightly and let it slide up or down. If I press it firmly to the left, it won't move up or down. It feels like, there is an obstacle, I need to get around. I am not sure how to explain it best, but basically, if I am in first gear and I try to move to second, it feels like there is an obstacle in the middle, I need to go around.

Maybe this illustration could help:

[image]

The blue circle is the clutch stick handle. The black straight line is the stick. The red arrow represents what is not working: Having the stick at the most left position and trying to move up. The green line represents what I have to do: move slightly right, then up. The black freehand lines represent some kind of obstacle, or hole, which prevents smooth movement on the left side. It feels similar on the right side, but not nearly as pronounced.

Is there a problem and if there is, what might be it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it sounds as though the issue lies with either a stiff gear linkage or an issue with the adjustment or alignment of the gear linkage.

I did a quick google search to see if I could track down the linkage adjustment guide specific to your vehicle but instead found links to forums and groups indicating you may not be alone; [here](http://forum.qashqaiclub.co.uk/cant-select-first-gear_topic9300.html) is an example thread.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that does sound like my issue. So I guess nothing to worry about?